# Why am I getting "Error: Promise is rejected." when trying to remove an item using AsyncStorage for React Native Windows?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to clear a few previously set items after a button press but when I run my app I'm seeing "Error: promise is rejected" and nothing else happens. I have been able to remove items in other projects using this exact same method but now it is throwing this error and I have 0 idea why.

Code below:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../Styles.js';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


export const Main = ({ navigation} ) => {
    const storeData = async () => {
        try {
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@currentClient")
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@currentDate")
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@currentLocation")
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@currentNotes")
          await AsyncStorage.removeItem("@currentAdvisor")
          navigation.push('Info')
        } catch (e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
      }

    return (
      <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
          <Image source={require('../images/appLogoNoBG.png')} style={styles.images} />
          <Text style={styles.mainText}>Island Solutions</Text>
          <Text style={styles.subText}>Initial Assessment</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => storeData()}> 
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>New Assessment</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>- Or -</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={() => navigation.push('LoadSelect')}> 
                <Text style={styles.btnText}>Load Assessment</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  )
  }

export default Main;
```

Console log:

```
Error: Promise is rejected.
    at convertError (C:\Users\Franc\Desktop\React\EasyAudit\node_modules\@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\src\AsyncStorage.native.js:452:15)
    at C:\Users\Franc\Desktop\React\EasyAudit\node_modules\@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\src\AsyncStorage.native.js:445:59
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at convertErrors (C:\Users\Franc\Desktop\React\EasyAudit\node_modules\@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\src\AsyncStorage.native.js:445:48)
    at C:\Users\Franc\Desktop\React\EasyAudit\node_modules\@react-native-async-storage\async-storage\src\AsyncStorage.native.js:169:22
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (C:\Users\Franc\Desktop\React\EasyAudit\node_modules\react-native-windows\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:465:13)
    at C:\Users\Franc\Desktop\React\EasyAudit\node_modules\react-native-windows\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:127:12
    at MessageQueue.__guard (C:\Users\Franc\Desktop\React\EasyAudit\node_modules\react-native-windows\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:370:9)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (C:\Users\Franc\Desktop\React\EasyAudit\node_modules\react-native-windows\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:126:10)
    at debuggerWorker.aca173c4.js:4:902
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever managed to find what was causing it? Thanks